# How to bind this within js nested object iteration within a function. Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, this

again, probably a terrible title - but what I'm trying to do is to make a simple search feature on my website. You click a nav button, which updates the search bar, whi in turn triggers an onchange event to update the current appended list.

```
function update() {
var list = $("#comic__modern-list");
list.empty();
$.each(Object.keys(comics), function() {
    var currentObject = comics[this];
    var filter = comics[this].type;
    var publisher = comics[this].publisher;
    if (search == "") {
        if(filter == "modern") {
                list.append(`
                    <div class="comic__box">
                    <div class="comic__image-box">
                    <img src="${currentObject['data-item-image']}" alt="${currentObject['data-item-description']}" class="img-fluid">
                    <div class="comic__desc-wrap">
                       <div class="comic__desc">${currentObject['data-item-description']}, issue #${currentObject['issue']} (${currentObject['year']})</div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="text-align:center; margin-top: 1rem">
                    <button 
                       class="btn btn-warning snipcart-add-item comic__button" 
                       data-item-id="${currentObject['data-item-id']}" 
                       data-item-price="${currentObject['data-item-price']}" 
                       data-item-url="${currentObject['data-item-url']}" 
                       data-item-description="${currentObject['data-item-description']}" 
                       data-item-image="${currentObject['data-item-image']}" 
                       data-item-name="${currentObject['data-item-name']}"> 
                       <div class="comic__desc-desk">£${currentObject['data-item-price']}<br>Add to cart</div><div class="comic__desc-mob">BUY <br> ${currentObject['data-item-description']}, Issue: ${currentObject['issue']} (${currentObject['year']})</div>
                    </button>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    `)   
        }
    } else if (search == publisher) {
         
            list.append(`
                    <div class="comic__box">
                    <div class="comic__image-box">
                    <img src="${currentObject['data-item-image']}" alt="${currentObject['data-item-description']}" class="img-fluid">
                    <div class="comic__desc-wrap">
                       <div class="comic__desc">${currentObject['data-item-description']}, issue #${currentObject['issue']} (${currentObject['year']})</div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="text-align:center; margin-top: 1rem">
                    <button 
                       class="btn btn-warning snipcart-add-item comic__button" 
                       data-item-id="${currentObject['data-item-id']}" 
                       data-item-price="${currentObject['data-item-price']}" 
                       data-item-url="${currentObject['data-item-url']}" 
                       data-item-description="${currentObject['data-item-description']}" 
                       data-item-image="${currentObject['data-item-image']}" 
                       data-item-name="${currentObject['data-item-name']}"> 
                       <div class="comic__desc-desk">£${currentObject['data-item-price']}<br>Add to cart</div><div class="comic__desc-mob">BUY <br> ${currentObject['data-item-description']}, Issue: ${currentObject['issue']} (${currentObject['year']})</div>
                    </button>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    `)
    
    }
    
    
});
```

}
The current list is generated by this, which works fine:

```
$.each(Object.keys(comics), function() {
        var currentObject = comics[this];
        var currentObject2 = comics[this].type;
        console.log(currentObject2);
        if (search == "") {
            if(currentObject2 == "modern") {
                var list = $("#comic__modern-list");
    
                    list.append(`
                        <div class="comic__box">
                        <div class="comic__image-box">
                        <img src="${currentObject['data-item-image']}" alt="${currentObject['data-item-description']}" class="img-fluid">
                        <div class="comic__desc-wrap">
                           <div class="comic__desc">${currentObject['data-item-description']}, issue #${currentObject['issue']} (${currentObject['year']})</div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="text-align:center; margin-top: 1rem">
                        <button 
                           class="btn btn-warning snipcart-add-item comic__button" 
                           data-item-id="${currentObject['data-item-id']}" 
                           data-item-price="${currentObject['data-item-price']}" 
                           data-item-url="${currentObject['data-item-url']}" 
                           data-item-description="${currentObject['data-item-description']}" 
                           data-item-image="${currentObject['data-item-image']}" 
                           data-item-name="${currentObject['data-item-name']}"> 
                           <div class="comic__desc-desk">£${currentObject['data-item-price']}<br>Add to cart</div><div class="comic__desc-mob">BUY <br> ${currentObject['data-item-description']}, Issue: ${currentObject['issue']} (${currentObject['year']})</div>
                        </button>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        `)   
            }
        }
        
        
    });
```

From what I can gather, this has to do with the keyword "this" no longer meaning what it did when it was outside of the function, so I'm assuming the fix will be to do with bind(), but I can't make heads nor tails of it.

p.s, if there's an easier/simpler way to set up a search system, please enlighten me!

Comment: What is the actually issue here? **this**, what's wrong with it? And is your code giving good result? What should be your expected result?

Comment: The expected result if that the list updates, filtering the js object to match the filter and appends the list with the new results

Comment: it's currenty emptying, but not hitting the else if statement

Comment: Sorted it! There was a spelling mistake not matching the field I was using to filter the results.